# The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception error while calling Stored Procedure from Azure function

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I have an `Azure Event hub` with readings from my smart electricity meter. I am trying to use an `Azure Function` to write the meter readings to an Azure SQL DB. I have created a target table in the Azure SQL DB and a Stored Procedure to parse a JSON and store the contents in the table. I have successfully tested the stored procedure.

When I call it from my Azure Function however I am getting an error: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. For testing purposes, I have tried to execute a simple SQL select statement from my Azure Function, but that gives the same error. I am lost at the moment as I have tried many options without any luck. Here is the Azure function code:

```cs
#r "Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs"

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using Dapper;

public static async Task Run(string events, ILogger log)
{
    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    try
      {
            if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(events))
                return;
            try{
                string ConnString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_azure-db-connection-meterreadevents", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

                using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
                {
                    conn.Execute("dbo.ImportEvents", new { Events = events }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function exception: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
            // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed to process so it can be processed again later.
            exceptions.Add(e);
        }

    // Once processing of the batch is complete if any messages in the batch failed process throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.

    if (exceptions.Count > 1)
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

    if (exceptions.Count == 1)
        throw exceptions.Single();
}
```

The events coming in are in JSON form as follows

```
{ 
   "current_consumption":450,
   "back_low":0.004,
   "current_back":0,
   "total_high":13466.338,
   "gas":8063.749,
   "current_rate":"001",
   "total_low":12074.859,
   "back_high":0.011,
   "timestamp":"2020-02-29 22:21:14.087210"
}
```

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ImportEvents]
@Events NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO dbo.MeterReadEvents

    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@Events) WITH (timestamp datetime2, current_consumption int, current_rate nchar(3), current_back int, total_low numeric(8, 3), back_high numeric(8, 3), total_high numeric(8, 3), gas numeric(7, 3), back_low numeric(8, 3))
END
```

I have added a connection string of type SQL AZURE and changed `{your password}` by the actual password in the string. Any thoughts on how to fix this issue or maybe how to get more logging as the error is very general?.

Comment: I have this issue too with .net472 .  I note the following Inner Exception 1:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception.

Inner Exception 2:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper' threw an exception.

Inner Exception 3:
Win32Exception: Failed to load D:\dev\myapp\bin\Debug\x64\SNI.dll

Comment: Try replacing all references to System.Data.SqlClient with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Comment: deleting `bin` and `obj` then `clean` and `rebuild solution` worked for me

Answer (score 7):

I managed to fix this exception by re-installing `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI`. Then `clean` and `rebuild` your project.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix the issue by changing the Runtime version to ~2 in the Function App Settings.

Does this mean this is some bug in runtime version ~3 or should there be another way of fixing it in runtime version ~3?

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to the party, in my case the cause of the error was "Target runtime" when publishing, I developed on windows machine but was transferring the file to linux, the solution was to change target runtime to the correct one, initial it was win-x64(merely because I started off by deploying locally), see screenshot below

[image: Target runtime change]

Answer (score 1):

After publishing the project I just copied only the .exe file inside the target runtime (win-x64) folder. Which gave me this exception. After running the file from inside the win-x64 folder it ran without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to a local SQL, use SQL profiler, and check what you are sending, and what precisely SQL is trying to do with the command being executed.

It's very hard to replicate your code, because, I obviously do not have your Azure SQL :)
So I would suggest, try to execute each step in the Stored procedure, as direct queries.

See if that works, then try to wrap the statements into store-procedures called back-to-back, and get that to work. 
Then combine the commands to a single command, and fiddle with it till you get it to work ;)

Get the most simple query to execute towards the Azure SQL, so you are sure your connection is valid. (Like just a simple select on something)

Because without more information, it is very difficult to assist you.

Comment: Thanks! I will have another look today. I already tried to send a very simple SQL (SELECT * FROM) and that gives the same error. Thus I expect something is wrong in the connection (string).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty silly but I got this after installing the EntityFrameworkCore Nuget package but not EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Nuget package. I had the SqlServer version for EntityFramework 6 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with a VSTO-application that was installed with a double click in the file explorer. Windows copied not all files to such an automatic location somewhere into ProgramData, so the application was simply not complete!

The solution was to register the VSTO-application manualy in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and pointed the "Manifest" to the complete directory with **all** the files. (like `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll`, `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll` etc)

Those automatically by Windows chosen installations/directories will give unexpected behaviour. :(

Answer (score 0):

Some ws methods ran fine and other would fail with this same error.  I ran ws method that was failing in the browser on the box that the ws was being served from and got a lengthy, and helpful error message.  One item was an InnerException that said

```
<ExceptionMessage>Failed to load C:\sites\TXStockChecker.xxxxxx.com\bin\x64\SNI.dll</ExceptionMessage>
```

I noticed that that file was right were it was expected in my development environment so I copied it to the matching directory on the prod ws and now all the methods run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

a little late but here is the answer:

I had the same problem and the only thing I did was update from version 1.1.0 of the SqlClient.SNI package to version 1.1.1.

[image]